# Difference between process.nextTick vs setImmediate

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have looked into web and similar threads in `stackoverflow`, but i am really not understanding  the difference between them and the scenarios where one would be useful compared to other.

Let me put my `understanding` in code wise.

```
function sum(a, b, cb){
    setImmediate(function(){
        cb(a + b)
    });
}

sum(10, 10, console.log);
console.log("Done")

function anotherSum(a,b,cb){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        cb(a + b);
    });
}

anotherSum(2, 3, console.log);

console.log("End")
```

Here using the `process.nextTick`/`setImmediate`, we are actually delaying the `callback` execution.

```
Output:

Done End 5 20
```

Both are delaying the execution of the `callback`, can anyone tell me the exact `difference` with some `example`.

Comment: Did you read the Node.js documentation?

Comment: @SLaks: I have read too many documentation, but i am not getting things clearly.

Comment: What part of http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback don't you understand?

Comment: All i am seeing in the web is nextTick() typically runs before any other I/O events fire and setImmediate runs after I/O events. I am not really getting this part visually.